# How to check exact substring in two or more strings

Tags: python

Consider the following two lists

```
list1 = ["tom","sam","ram","omlet"]
list2 = ["com","dome","mom","omega"]
```

With the following code the output is True for every condition:

```
for a,b in zip(list1,list2):
    cond = "om" in (a and b)
    print(cond)
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
True
True
```

As the corresponding elements "sam" and "dome" from list1 and list2 only "dome" have "om", so it should fail the condition?, But the ouput is True.

How to check the condition if substring  "om" matches **exactly** for both the strings in the corresponding elements of the lists.

Expected output:

```
True
False
False
True
```

Comment: `"om" in (a and b)` isn't doing what you think.  Use `"om" in a and "om" in b` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There you are:

```
list1 = ["tom","sam","ram","omlet"]
list2 = ["com","dome","mom","omega"]

for a,b in zip(list1,list2):
    cond = ("om" in a) and ('om' in b)
    print(cond)
```

Output:

```
True
False
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something you don't want with `in (a and b)` - you're checking for existence only in latter as (a and b) gives b. You need:

```
cond = "om" in a and "om" in b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    list1 = ["tom","sam","ram","omlet"]
    list2 = ["com","dome","mom","omega"]
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        cond=("om" in list1[i]) and ("om" in list2[i])
        print(cond)
```

It will print your expected output

```
True
False
False
True
```